# how to turn of gps when application stops in android application

Tags: android

I need to turn of the gps when the application stops, The gps is used globally and it is used in every Activity, how can I get an event when the app is closed?

Comment: Should the GPS be running when the application is running but in the background (ie. not visible to the user)?

Answer (score 1):

use use the remove the update on onPause it makes save the drain of battery

```
  @Override 
   protected void onPause() 
     { 
      super.onPause();
      if(locationmanager != null) { 
        locationmanager .removeUpdates(locationlistner); 
      } 
      locationlistner = null;  
    }
```